# Reusing nested components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to reuse Vue component which is nested inside parent component, after that parent component is swapped for another component?

My motivation is that I need to have something like "resource component" which is placed in DOM without any re-rendering and to assign it alternately to "consumer components" that make use of its capabilities. To be more specific, in my use case there is one component with `<video>` element, that is capable to play different sources. And then I have different components for each source, for example: video file, stream, webcam... The main restrictions come from the target platform, which can handle only a limited number of `<video>` elements and produces unexpected bugs when removing / adding / moving `<video>` elements in DOM.

Basically, it is very similar to [this example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key) from the documentation. But I need to reuse `<input>` element with this markup:

```
<template v-if="loginType === 'username'">
    <label>Username</label>
    <foo>
        <input placeholder="Enter your username">
    </foo>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <label>Email</label>
    <bar>
        <input placeholder="Enter your email address">
    </bar>
</template>
```

Both parent components (`<foo>` and `<bar>`) shouldn't render anything to DOM, while `<input>` should remain in DOM without any moves or re-rendering or changes in HTMLElement state.

So far I have tried these implementations, but none of them fully satisfies my requirements:

- I have tried using `key`, but it seems to work only for the components with the same name. `<foo key="baz">` and `<bar key="baz">` won't reuse nested `<input>`.
- I have tried using `key` on different the components with the same name, but the result remained the same.
- I have tried adding undocumented config `abstract: true` for the `<foo>` and `<bar>` components (same as the `<template>` in the example), but again no reuse of `<input>`, probably because of the different component names.
- I have tried using `keep-alive` component, but it seems to reuse virtual DOM rather than real DOM, which I need.
- I have managed to reuse the `<input>` component with config `functional: true` for the `<foo>` and `<bar>` components. But this makes the components stateless (no reactive data) and instanceless (no this context), so it's impossible for them to effectively communicate with the `<input>` component.
- I have tried to replace both `<foo>` and `<bar>` components with another component `<baz>`, to make reuse with `key` working. But I failed to implement some sort of delegation of implementation from `<baz>` to `<foo>` and `<bar>` based on the current requirements.